# Making Vue Select component reusable (Laravel), returns [object Object]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm trying to create a reusable select component - initially, just to prove things were working I loaded the select directly in the vue file - which works with data.

I have the following in php controller:

```
$countries = Country::pluck('name', 'id');

return Inertia::render('Create', compact('countries'));
```

In the Create.vue file I tested this code which works:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="selCountry">
<option v-for="(country, id) in countries" :key="id" :value="id">
{{ country }}
</option>
</select>
```

When I tried to make the select component reuseable, I would keep getting [object Object] being returned here is the code:

Select-Component.vue

```
<template>
  <select
    class="form-control"
    @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    ref="select"
  >
    <option
      v-for="(data, key) in options"
      :key="key"
      :value="key"
      :selected="data === modelValue"
    >
      {{ data }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["modelValue", "options"],

  emits: ["update:modelValue"],

  methods: {
    focus() {
      this.$refs.select.focus();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Btw here is some example data that is being passed from php to vue:

```
    101 => "Germany"
    225 => "UK"
```

Thanks in advance.

and finally loading the component with:

```
<select id="countries" :options="countries" />
```

**Update:** sorry just to add I am trying to achieve this without using any npm packages.

Thanks

Comment: How are you using that component?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with vue but I *think* `data` would be an object rather than an array  because the countries array has non-incrementing integer keys (and don't start from 0) which get converted to a JavaScript object. Try using `select('id', 'name')` instead of `pluck` and then using `data.id` and `data.name` to refer to the identifier and name. It's odd that the first piece of code would work though